# One timestamp with multiple formatting outputs

Tags: php, javascript, unix-timestamp

I want to display two dates/times on my page

- the server one, taken from the MySQL Server
- the client one, taken from JavaScript

Since the output wasn't right, I started digging through my code and found something weird: I formatted the same timestamp in both php and javascript (see the code below) and the results differed by 3 hours.

timestamp: 1369855189

PHP:

```
var_dump( date( 'H:i:s', $timestamp ) );
```

*Output*: "19:19:49"

JavaScript:

```
dts = new Date( timestamp * 1000 );
var hours_s = dts.getHours();
var minutes_s = dts.getMinutes();
var seconds_s = dts.getSeconds();
current_server_time = hours_s + ":" + minutes_s + ":" + seconds_s";
```

*Output*: "22:19:49"

Does anyone know why this is happening? Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Sorry for how the question looks, I tried formatting it as suggested, but apparently failed :(

Comment: Looks like different timezones-

Comment: JS parses all dates in the local time zone unless such timezone info if provided in the date serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and your server are probably not on the same timezome.

Try with javascript:

```
    var hours_s = dts.getUTCHours();
    var minutes_s = dts.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds_s = dts.getUTCSeconds();
```

Comment: I was actually working locally, ie my pc was the server. Nevertheless, it worked. Thanks, you're a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp will be UTC...but once you put it into a PHP date object, it will have the timezone of the server.  Once you put it into JavaScript, it will have the computer's local timezone.  To set the timezone of the server in PHP, you can use this (replacing the timezone with yours) and see if that fixes it for you:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago')
```

Obviously, to change the timezone for JavaScript requires changing your computer's timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Is the php being executed in a server different from the machine where the JavaScript is parsed?
Either way, there is a workaround if you can work with **gmt** time:

> Use the *[gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)* in your PHP script.
>   Use dts.*getUTCHours()* (and similar functions for the rest, prefixing UTC) in your JS. Check the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) *p. 174*. for more details.

If you want to work with local time, review the locale configuration of both server and client machines.